# How to check and turn on pilot light of this water tank?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water, pilot-light

I have never done this before but the gas line was turned off briefly and now we have no hot water.

Look like the pilot light went out on this but I have no idea how to see the light and how to turn it on.

[image]

I looked on the internet and it said to turn to pilot and push down but it didn't do anything

Looking for advise. Thank you

Comment: Did you try the instructions on the heater -- see that big sticker just above the pilot button?

Comment: "Was turned off briefly" not by the gas company, clearly.   Future reference, you only turn gas lines off.  You call the gas company to turn them back on. This is free.  Reason is most pilots are *not* auto-shutoff like that one. When gas is restored they will not self-light (obviously) and will instead hemorrhage gas into the house until it is full of gas and kaboom.    All that said, modulo the fact that we *are* a DIY forum, and it's possible to DIY and not botch it.  I'll call the gas company because the liability is so high if I do botch it.

Comment: please add a picture of the instructions

Comment: the button on top may be the igniter and on/off control in one .... does it make a loud "thump" sound when you press it down? (like a gas barbecue igniter, if you are familiar with one)  ......... take off the cover at the bottom of the heater and look inside .... you should be able to see a small blue flame if the pilot light is lit (like a cigarette lighter on lowest setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are detailed instructions on the water heater, text and diagrams, but the following is my recollections.

If the gas tap at the end of the house supply piping is turned off, the knobs on the heater will be in the operating positions.

1. Turn the main control on the tank off and then turn it to a position that will be labeled "Pilot". (Maybe just turn it to "Pilot".) Open the cover on the burner compartment so you can see inside.
2. Turn the smaller "pilot" valve to a position (usu 90 deg) which will allow the valve to be pushed down against a spring. Holding the valve down opens a safety valve and allows gas to flow *to the pilot only*.
3. While holding this valve down try to ignite the pilot by pressing an igniter button. Observe whether the pilot lights. If it does, continue to hold the button down for 15 seconds or so after the pilot lights so that the heat of the pilot can warm a sensor that allows it to stay on. If you release the button too soon, the pilot will go out.

If the pilot does not light with that press of the igniter, then continue to hold the pilot valve down, wait 15 sec, and press the igniter button again.

4. Turn the pilot valve to the operating position.
5. Turn the main valve to its operating position and desired temperature. When you do this the main gas burner should come on and start heating the water in the tank. In 30 min or so you will have usable warmed water in the tank.
6. Close the cover on the burner compartment.

**EDIT**

http://www.home-repair-central.com/how-to-light-a-water-heater.html

Comment: I read similar instructions online but still have questions: (1) Where is the pilot light? Is it covered somewhere? (2) Where is the ignite button? I could push down the valve but see no igniter button.

Comment: The pilot light is inside the burner chamber. It looks to me like you open the door to the burner chamber by grasping protrusion of the metal cover and compressing it to release the latch which is probably on the left, then swing out the cover which may be hinged on the right. Could you give us the mfgr and model number of the heater? Was the gas turned off at the tap that is right by the the heater or was it turned off at the gas meter? I think at this point you should get the gas company to restore the supply to the heater.

Comment: The piece of sheet metal with the protruding curve is the door to the burner compartment. If you grasp it with your right hand, use your right thumb to compress the left side of the protrusion to release the edge. Then swing it out and away.